# How to Trim white spaces of string in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I have two tables:

Target table: `Specialisation (id , name , description)`

Source table `TempSpecialisation(id , name , description)`

I want to copy `TempSpe.description` to `Specialisation.Description` if the name matches or insert a new record in `Specialisation` with all the columns. 
I get duplicate entries because of white space at the end of `Specialisation.name`.

My procedure is:

```
USE [TempDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TempDatabase2]    Script Date:      23/12/2015 3:46:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempDatabase2]
WITH EXECUTE AS owner
as
BEGIN 

MERGE Specialisation as T
USING TempSpecialisation as S
ON s.Name = T.Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
THEN INSERT(id ,Name, Description1) VALUES(S.id ,S.Name, S.Description1)
WHEN MATCHED and t.name =s.name
THEN UPDATE SET T.Description1 = S.Description1 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
End
```

Table Specialisation

```
id       Name           Descriptions
545454   "Allergist  "  null
```

Table TEmpSpecialisation

```
id       Name         Descriptions
1        "Allergist"  This is a doctor who helps with allergies.
```

I need to update Specialisation description from TEmpSpecialisation. 
but it give output like

```
id       Name           Descriptions  
1        "Allergist"    This is a doctor who helps with allergies. 
545454   "Allergist  "  null
```

Comment: `id` column - identity?

Comment: If this line doing correct update operation THEN UPDATE SET T.Description1 = S.Description1  I think this should be  THEN UPDATE SET  S.Description1 =T.Description1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name))` to remove white space from the beginning and the end of the field, so your merge statement becomes:

```
MERGE Specialisation as T
USING TempSpecialisation as S
ON LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(T.Name))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
THEN INSERT(id ,Name, Description1) VALUES(S.id ,S.Name, S.Description1)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET T.Description1 = S.Description1 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
End
```

[LTRIM Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx)

[RTRIM Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

Comment: USE [TempDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempDatabase2]
WITH EXECUTE AS owner
as
BEGIN 

MERGE Specialisation as T
USING TempSpecialisation as S
ON (LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Name))) = (LTRIM(RTRIM(T.Name))) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target 
    THEN INSERT(id ,Name, Description1) VALUES(S.id ,S.Name, S.Description1)
WHEN MATCHED and t.name =s.name
    THEN UPDATE SET T.Description1 = S.Description1 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
End

Still not worked!! duplicate Entry :(

Comment: There are whitespace characters not removed by the TRIM functions.  Try combining the RIGHT and ASCII functions to see what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TempDatabase2]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.Specialisation T
    USING dbo.TempSpecialisation S ON LTRIM(S.Name) = LTRIM(T.Name)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (id, Name, Description1)
            VALUES (S.id, S.Name, S.Description1)
    WHEN MATCHED AND ISNULL(T.Description1, '') != ISNULL(S.Description1, '') -- remove ISNULL if Description1 NOT NULL
        THEN
            UPDATE SET T.Description1 = S.Description1
    OUTPUT $ACTION, INSERTED.*;

END
```

Comment: Still it returned duplicate entry.
NAme is like "Allergist  " 
two spaces . but i dont thing it matters.

Comment: please provide a small dataset for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
ON CHARINDEX(s.name,t.name) = 1
```

Its working now!!
thank you